# Is it possible to activate and execute virtualenv Python from TCL?

Tags: python, tcl, virtualenv

This is the bash command that I execute:

```
  source ./virtualenv/Scripts/activate && cd ./deps/scripts && python generate_system_info.py
```

Now I want to run this from within a TCL script. I am not sure how this can be achieved.

I know that the `exec` in TCL is required. However, I am not sure if I can do the activate of virtualenv from TCL using the method shown above. I am also not sure how to integrate the `&&` when I make call to `exec` inside the TCL shell.

Is what I am trying to achieve even possible?

The TCL shell is from a program called Xilinx Vivado.

Answer (score 2):

The `activate` script (made from [this template](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/15c09d6e0c1eb11c18918ef67590e5291fd361f0/src/virtualenv/activation/bash/activate.sh) by obvious substitutions) sets these environment variables (that you need to care about):

1. `VIRTUAL_ENV` — The path of the root of the virtual environment.
2. `PATH` — Where binaries are found by... lots of programs! This is *extended* by the script.
3. `PS1` — The system prompt.

It also *removes* the `PYTHONHOME` environment variable (if it was set) and defines a function called `deactivate` to undo all this.

---

To do the equivalent in `tclsh` when running Python as a subprocess, you usually just need to set the first two variables (and do that remove). The clean up happens automatically when Tcl exits. (We omit configuring the prompt; you would only need that if working interactively.)

```
proc activatePythonVirtualEnvironment {path} {
    global env tcl_platform
    # Allow standard Tcl paths
    set path [file nativename [file normalize $path]]
    set binpath [file nativename [file join [file normalize $path] bin]]
    
    # We can just set this here
    set env(VIRTUAL_ENV) $path

    # Prepend the right form; good thing we have a special global to help
    set env(PATH) $binpath$tcl_platform(pathSeparator)$env(PATH)

    # Eliminate this environment variable if it is set
    unset -nocomplain env(PYTHONHOME)
}
```

After that, you can `exec` as normal and things will Just Work™.

```
activatePythonVirtualEnvironment ./virtualenv/
cd deps/scripts
exec python generate_system_info.py
```

Comment: Don't need an equivalent `&&` in Tcl; Tcl uses errors/exceptions when things go wrong so you can assume preceding things succeeded. (`&&` has a more C-like meaning)

Comment: Actually the reason I was using && is like this, I think that when I call exec, a bash will be created which will activate the Python virtualenv, and then at the end the bash will be destroyed. Therefore, I need to do everything in one line and use &&. Is this the wrong approach? Isn't a new shell spawned each time we run exec? Also, I was trying to first run the command in interactive TCL shell of the Xilinx Vivado.

Comment: Another thing that I have realized is that, it is possible to directly run the virtualenv python.exe which is the in the same folder as the activate scripts. However, I believe that this is not a good idea. Is my approach correct?

Comment: Just running that binary is a valid approach. It's how I've been doing it with IDE integrations (where I've got quite a few virtual environments to support testing the code against different Python versions).

Comment: I am getting this error when I execute the script in Vivado TCL shell: "[runtcl-4] can't read "tcl_platform(pathSeparator)": no such element in array". What do I do now?

Comment: @Donal Fellows, I am also getting this erro "[runtcl-4] can't read "tcl_platform(pathSeparator)": no such element in array". What do I do now?

Answer (score 1):

From the [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) documentation:

> You don’t specifically need to activate an environment; activation
> just prepends the virtual environment’s binary directory to your path,
> so that “python” invokes the virtual environment’s Python interpreter
> and you can run installed scripts without having to use their full
> path. However, all scripts installed in a virtual environment should
> be runnable without activating it, and run with the virtual
> environment’s Python automatically.

So basically `activate` just replaces path to your python script (and `$PATH` environment variable, at least in linux). You can just run *proper* python from `virtualenv` directory using full/relative path.

If you struggle where it is, you can activate `virtualenv` and use `which` command to find it out!

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else, you can execute the whole pipeline like this:

```
exec bash -c {source ./virtualenv/Scripts/activate && cd ./deps/scripts && python generate_system_info.py}
```

The `&&` just says "if the previous command succeeded, continue on to the next command".  Thus, you could do those three commands on three separate lines.  The PROBLEM is that `source` command.  It needs to set environment variables in the current process, and by default tcl would launch a subshell, and when that subshell ended the environment would go away.  You CAN set local environment variables in tcl, so maybe the option would be to convert that `activate` shell script into tcl commands.  Then you could do

```
activate.tcl
cd deps/scripts
exec python generate_system_info.py
```

Comment: wouldn't running `../../virtualenv/Script/python` instead of activating virtualenv be easier and had the same effect?

Comment: I don't know the virtual environment implementation.  If that works, then it's surely better and you should post that as an answer.

Comment: `source` is not a valid portable `sh` command. Whether `activate` will work with `sh` is a separate question.

Comment: what is the -c switch exactly? It works with that switch but not without it.

Comment: The `-c` says to take the commands from the following string, as opposed to reading from stdin like it usually would.  https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash